# Fetch UIElement by using accessibilityIdentifier in UIAutomation

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am using profiler and UIAutomation to write tests for my iOS app.

How can I fetch UIElement to whom I have assigned accessibilityIdentifier in code? Here is my problem. I have an Universal app that runs on iPad and iPhone. View is different on these devices. I have 2 slightly different Xib files. On iPhone i have ScrollBar containing UILabel. On iPad I have ScrollBar containing UIView containing UILabel. These labels are contacted to the same IBOutlet. I have assigned accessibilityIdentifier to the IBOutlet.

How can I fetch my label from JavaScript using accessibilityIdentifier? Can it be done with the same code on iPad and on iPhone?

Something like

```
var label = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().elements()["myAccesibilityIdentifier"];
UIALogger.logMessage("Is label valid? " + label.isValid());
```

As a result I get 
Is label valid? false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your automation code you can discern whether or not your running iPad vs iPhone (example)

```
if(target.model()=="iPhone" || target.model() == "iPhone Simulator")
{
    var phone = true;
    var pad   = false;
    var appName = app.name();
    UIALogger.logMessage("Testing device is: iPhone");
    UIALogger.logMessage("Logger says: " + target.model()); 
    UIALogger.logMessage("Application name: " + appName);
}   
else if(target.model() =="iPad" || target.model() == "iPad Simulator")
{   
    var phone = false;
    var pad   = true;
    var appName = app.name();
    UIALogger.logMessage("Testing device is: iPad");
    UIALogger.logMessage("Logger says: " + target.model());
    UIALogger.logMessage("Application name: " + appName);
}
```

based on the variables phone/pad that I set in the example you can instruct your script how to find the element you are looking for.

```
if(phone)
{
    //var label = Path to element (phone)
}
else if(pad)
{
    //var label = Path to element (pad)
}
```

I know the use of pad/phone together is redundant, but I did that originally to be safe in case a third type gets mixed into iOS development in the future (Just in case ;)).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Mechanic (https://github.com/jaykz52/mechanic). You can access elements by name, and it will search the view hierarchy for you. e.g.

```
var label = $('#myAccesibilityIdentifier');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if this could be solved without using 3rd party stuff? I guess the problem is common. UI will defer from iPad and iPhone so I figure Apple has to have a solution for this.

Comment: As far as I can see, Apple puts little to no emphasis on UIAutomation. I doubt they use it internally. Has it even improved a little in iOS 8? I didn't see any news from WWDC about it.

Comment: @GrahamPerks, in my personal opinion. UIAutomation has actually gotten worse on the iOS side with iOS 8. During WWDC they made mention as to how proud they were of their automating features as they added a major upgrade to automating tasks in OSX (Yosemite). However, when it came to running automation on iOS there were changes that did not get logged into the Xcode release notes. Main thing that changed was the placement of a template file which is used for running UIAutomation from Terminal (and a handful of third party tools rely on the absolute path to this file). As well as other issues.